# RegExp получить любое значение между символами с самими символами

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

пытаюсь получить значение в стринге между символами и немного не хватает опыта в написании RegExp. Буду рад любой помощи.

У меня есть стрига `Hello ___world___` из нее мне нужно получить `_world_`. вместо `world` может быть другое любое значение. К примеру:

`Hello ______` -> должно вернуть null/undefined

`Hello ___world__` -> должно вернуть `_world_`

`Hello ___wor_l_d___` -> должно вернуть `_wor_l_d_`

`Hello __*$world__` -> должно вернуть `_*$world_`

`Hello world__` -> должно вернуть null/undefined

Сейчас у меня выходит так:

```js
const reg = /(?<=_)(.*)(?=_)/;
const string1 = "Hello ___world___";
const string2 = "Hello ______";
const string3 = "Hello ___wor_l_d___";
const string4 = "Hello ___*$world___";
const string5 = "Hello world__";

console.log(string1.match(reg));
console.log(string2.match(reg));
console.log(string3.match(reg));
console.log(string4.match(reg));
console.log(string5.match(reg));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```js
/_[^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*_/g
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/LmGqS0/1).

*Подробности*:

- `_` - символ `_`
- `[^_]+` - один и более символов, отличных от символа `_`
- `(?:_[^_]+)*` - ноль и более повторов символа `_`, за которым следует один и более символов, отличных от символа `_`
- `_` - символ `_`.

См. пример работы кода на JavaScript:

```js
const reg = /_[^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*_/g;
const strings = ["Hello ___world___", "Hello ______", "Hello ___wor_l_d___", "Hello ___*$world___", "Hello world__"];
for (const s of strings) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.match(reg)?.[0]);
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!